# How do I ask the user how many inputs they want to enter, and then have python display that number of inputs

Tags: python-3.x

How do I ask the user for  a number of inputs and display the inputs which they asked for?

For example if I asked the user (('how many names would you like to enter')) and then I wrote the conditional statements and the program displayed ((Enter a name))  based on how many names the user wanted to input it would display that many inputs.

The goal of the exercise is to ask for a certain number of inputs execute that and append them into an empty list.

output:
ex.[kay,ray,may,jay]

Comment: Thanks in advance to anyone who answers this question for me.

Comment: Hi and welcome!  On SO you need to show what you've tried so far, and then if you hit specific code issues, come back and  check if there's an answer to them here (there probably will be) or ask a new question if not